# How do you set the 16 Terminal Colors for Git-Bash?

Tags: windows, git, cmd, git-bash

Is there a different way to set the 16 terminal colors for git-bash? Ideally, I'd like to know the location of a config file so that editing is easier, and the settings are portable.

It seems the only way I can see so far is to manually edit the boxes from the properties window, but this is buggy and tedious - you can't use hex strings, and selecting the color to inspect it sometimes alters the color wildly.

[image: Properties Window]

<del>Since git-bash is an old version of mintty,</del> I tried altering my .bashrc [their way](https://github.com/karlin/mintty-colors-solarized), but that failed to work as well. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: git-bash isn't a version of mintty. It uses the Windows console subsystem, like a command prompt window. You might be able to find some registry hacks for it.

Comment: Maybe you were thinking of (or looking for) [git-windows-mintty](https://github.com/rpavlik/git-windows-mintty). That should allow you to use the MinTTY method to change the colors.

Comment: I found a registry entry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` which looked promising. I was able to change the colors for CMD.exe directly, but not the git bash window. Which is odd, as there's a folder explicitly for git bash that I would have expected the window to source from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Console colors are stored in the registry under HKCU/Console/[window name]/ColorTable00-15.

[window name] is either "Git Bash" for the start menu entry or something like "C:_Program Files (x86)_Git_git-cheetah_.._bin_sh.exe" for the Windows Explorer context menu entry (supplied by Git-Cheetah).

Alternatively, the registry settings can be overridden by storing an NT_CONSOLE_PROPS structure with appropriate ColorTable settings in the "Git Bash.lnk" shortcut via IShellLinkDataList::AddDataBlock. This happens e.g. if you edit the properties of a console window started via shortcut, or if you edit the shortcut properties directly.

If you want the values from the registry instead, create a new "Git Bash.lnk" shortcut from scratch and leave the Options/Font/Layout/Colors tabs alone.

Comment: >If you want the values from the registry instead, create a new "Git Bash.lnk" shortcut.<

This is what I needed to see. I didn't know that console settings were bound to the shortcut. This explains why my registry editing had no effect - I was using the same link to load bash every time.